# Frobenius norm of prolate matrix

Tags: fourier-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm interested in the $N \times N$ matrix $A$ with Dirichlet entries
\begin{align}
a_{n,m}=\frac{\sin \left(\pi\eta(n-m)\right)}{\sin \left(\pi\eta (n-m)/{N}\right)}.
\end{align}
I found that
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{squared sum of diagonal entries }(=N^3)}{\text{squared Frobenius norm of } A} \approx \eta
\end{align}
as $N$ becomes large, with numerical experiment. What approach should I try to prove this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have derived it with early results on prolate matrices.
It is well-known that, as $N$ becomes large, nearly $\eta N$ nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ are clustered to $N/\eta$. Hence
\begin{align}
\|A\|_F^2\approx (\eta N)\times (N/\eta)^2 =N^3/\eta.
\end{align}

Comment: what do you mean by "power of the diagonal entries"?

Comment: @JackyChong Just a squared sum of diagonal entries, i.e. \sum a_{nn}^2.

Comment: So, do you have a proof? I don't know whether you already know the answer or not to your own question.